# Experiences with Microsoft eLearning

Tags: language-agnostic

I was browsing through Mirosoft training website and found that they offer quite a bunch of online courses. Does anyone have any experience with these?

Comment: as a corollary: are they actually useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been forced to complete some of these dreadful E-learnings, I can tell you that they are boring. They do a very good job of blasting you in the face with all the theoretical knowledge, but they do a poor job of preparing you for the code you will see in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

These are useful in discovering the way that someone in marketing in Microsoft imagines that their software / APIs will be used; they have little to no value in the real world.

Comment: @Molex: believe me, I toned down much of my actual opinion for this answer...  :-)